# Script in google sheets to open multi urls in group tab

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-sheets

I can't seem to find out the function, if there is one that opens up URLs in the new Google feature "Open all in new tab group". I just want to make a script and assign it to a button, that opens up all the URLs in group tab. For now, I just have a function that opens up them in separates tabs. If there is a function, is it possible to assign them color to the group tab also? (the preselected colors of group tabs)

I have tried looking for a group tab function. For now, I have a script that opens up all separately.

```
function openTabs(urls) {
  if(!Array.isArray(urls))
    urls = [urls];

  var html = 
    "<script>" + 
      urls.map(function(url) {
        return "window.open('" + url + "');";
      })
      .join('') +
      "google.script.host.close();" + 
    "</script>"; 

  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  .setWidth( 90 )
  .setHeight( 1 );

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening...');
}

function testOpenTabs() {
  var urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/'];
  openTabs(urls);
}
```

It worked yesterday through script editor. Now I get "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again." when trying to runt it.

Comment: If I understand correctly your main goal is to do something similar the [feature for grouping tabs in Chrome](https://blog.google/products/chrome/manage-tabs-with-google-chrome/), is that correct?

Comment: Indeed. That is what I am looking for. Don't know if it is possible though